# SAPUI5 hybrid mobile app - What happens on a failed flush()?

Tags: sapui5, offline, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, sap-mobile-services

I have a hybrid mobile app developed SAP Web IDE, SAP Cloud Platform using Hybrid App Toolkit (HAT) to build through SAP Mobile Services.

Say, for example, I perform a `flush()` (Update online database with offline OData) and there's a network error.

What happens next?

- The offline OData has been updated.
- The online OData is not updated.

Are the requests still queued, to be flushed on the next `flush()`?